# Performance issue while using PictureBox

Tags: winforms, performance, c++-cli, picturebox

I'm working on an application in Visual Studio 2010 and I'm coding in C++/CLI.
In my previous questions I had issue with data series from a serial port. Now it seems ok and  now I'm trying to plot them.
I don't want to use `Chart`, so I would like to use handmade functions that use the class `Graphics`. In order to test my code, I created two arrays: the first one is filled with values coming from a Gaussian. The second one is filled with random numbers.
When I plot the values, I would like to see my plot growing and updating just like an oscilloscope. The second `Do_Plot` manages to "remove point" plotting them by the BackColor.
All the code works as intended but I'm experiencing problem with performances. If I run the code on my Pc, my series is plotted every 500/700 ms.
Sometimes it slows down to 1500ms and then it comes back faster.
I tried to run the code on my coworkers' Pc and I noticed the series is plotted every 170ms on the first one, whereas the series is plotted every 950ms on the second one. 
This is the code:

```
System::Void Form1::button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    button1->Enabled = false;

    array<float,1>^ Gauss = gcnew array<float,1>(1001);

    array<float,1>^ Rumore = gcnew array<float,1>(1001);


     /*Some useful variables*/
     Random^ generatore = gcnew Random;
     float a = safe_cast<float>(Math::Round(5/(SIGMA*Math::Sqrt(2*PI)), 2));
     float b = safe_cast<float>(2*(SIGMA*SIGMA));

      /*Start */


      float portante; 
      float r;
      float s;

      int convX =1000/1000;
      int convY =500/2;  

      /*time variables */  

      int bias = 50;
      int dif =600;  

      /*Gap between drawing and removing*/  

      int k = 3; 
      int e1 = 0;


     for ( ; ; ) {

          /*Start*/
          clock_t Start = clock();

          if(textBox1->Text==""){
            portn = 5;
          }
          else
            portn = float::Parse(textBox1->Text);

          /*temp variables to go out the for cycle */
          portante = portn;
          r = rand;
          s = sig;

          /ckeck state is OK */
          check = 0;


            for(int i = 1; i<=1000; i++) {

                Gauss[i] = safe_cast<float>(Math::Round( a*s*Math::Exp(-Math::Pow(((0.01*1*(i))-portante), 2)/b), 2));

                Rumore[i] = safe_cast<float>(Math::Round(r*generatore->NextDouble(), 2));
                bool clipSup = ClipSup(2, Gauss[i]+Rumore[i]);

                if(clipSup==true) {
                    Gauss[i] = 1.99f;
                    Rumore[i] = 0;
                }
                Do_Plot(g, disegna, i-1, Gauss[i-1]+Rumore[i-1], i, Gauss[i]+Rumore[i], convX, convY);


                e1 =(k+i)%1000;
                Do_Plot(g, rimuovi, e1, Gauss[e1]+Rumore[e1], e1+1, Gauss[e1+1]+Rumore[e1+1], convX, convY);




                /*Ckeck if go out for cycle*/
                if(check == CODE_1 ) {
                    portante = portn;
                    break;
                }
                if(check == CODE_2 ) {
                    r = rand;
                    break;
                }
                if(check == CODE_3 ) {
                    s = sig;
                    break;
                }

            }

             clock_t Stop = clock();
             int Diff = Stop-Start;
             label8->Text = Convert::ToString(Diff);
             int tempDiff = (Stop-Start)+bias;
             if(tempDiff>dif)
             {

                //Do_Axes(g);           /*Do Axes*/
                //Do_Grid(g);           /*Do Grid */
                Application::DoEvents();
                dif = 600;
                bias = 0;
            }
            else
                bias +=50; //Else bias grows
      }


}
```

Where `Do_Plot` is:

```
void Do_Plot(Graphics^ g, Pen^ penna, int Xi, float Yi, int Xf, float Yf, int convX, int convY) {


    g->DrawLine(penna, (convX*Xi+50), safe_cast<int>(500-(Yi*convY)+50), 
        (convX*Xf+50), safe_cast<int>(500-(Yf*convY)+50)); 
}
```

I have declared `Graphics^ g` here:

```
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
Graphics^ g; 
public:
    Form1(void) 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: aggiungere qui il codice del costruttore.
        //
        g = pictureBox1->CreateGraphics();

    }
```

Onestly I don't know why my code works so differently when it runs on another Pc. I think the problem is `g = pictureBox1->CreateGraphics();` but I'm just doing some hypothesis. Any kind of help would be really appreciated cause I'm stuck on this one since the previous week!!
Thanks a lot!
Emiliano

Comment: Are you sure that the `Do_Plot()` is slowing down the process and not the math involved in the loop? If you want **real** fast drawings use plain GDI not GDI+.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I don't think the math is the problem. If the function is not called, every loop lasts about 1 ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to give you the code in c/c++. Will then find how to do it in c++/cli

First initialize the objects we will use (begining of button_click):

```
RECT rt = {0, 0, 1200, 600};
HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;
HPEN hLinePen = NULL;
HDC hdcPctrBox = NULL, hdc = NULL, hdcMemTempImage = NULL;
HBRUSH hBrush = NULL;
POINT arrayPnt[1000]; //array of points

hdc = CreateIC(TEXT("DISPLAY"), NULL, NULL, NULL);
hdcPctrBox = GetWindowDC(hwndPctrBox); //hwndPctrBox is the handle of picturebox
hdcMemTempImage = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 1200, 600);  
SelectObject(hdcMemTempImage, hBitmap);  

hLinePen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 0, 0)); //width of pen = 1,and color (255, 0, 0)
SelectObject(hdcMemTempImage, hLinePen);

hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(100, 100, 255)); //color of picturebox
```

Then:

```
for ( ; ; ) {
    /*Start*/
    clock_t Start = clock();

    FillRect(hdcMemTempImage, &rt, hBrush); //clear the hdcMemTempImage with the picturebox color
    //your code continues...
```

In the `for(int i = 1; i<=1000; i++)` add **one** point at a time:

```
arrayPnt[i - 1].x = X; //calculate X
arrayPnt[i - 1].x = Y; ////calculate Y
```

And finaly we draw it, after the for loop and before the clock_t Stop (we dont need the Do_Plot()):

```
Polyline(hdcMemTempImage, &arrayPnt, 1000);
BitBlt(hdcPctrBox, 0, 0, 1200, 600, hdcMemTempImage, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

clock_t Stop = clock();
//your code continues...
```

EDIT: use your original code(**you dont need** *rt, hBitmap, hBrush, hdcMemTempImage, arrayPnt and hdc*) and instead of calling `Do_Plot()` add this code:

```
//create two pens, one with the color you want hLinePen, and another with the color of picturebox hLinePenErase
//inside for(int i = 1; i<=1000; i++)
(some code...)
if(clipSup==true) {
    Gauss[i] = 1.99f;
    Rumore[i] = 0;
}

SelectObject(hdcPctrBox, hLinePen); //the pen to draw the line
MoveToEx(hdcPctrBox, xStart, yStart, NULL); //start point of line
LineTo(hdcPctrBox, xEnd, yEnd); //end point of line

SelectObject(hdcPctrBox, hLinePenErase); //the pen to erase the line
MoveToEx(hdcPctrBox, xStartErase, yStartErase, NULL); //start point of line to erase
LineTo(hdcPctrBox, xEndErase, yEndErase); //end point of line to erase
(code continues...)
```

To delete your resources:

```
HPEN hLinePen = NULL, hLinePenErase = NULL, originalPen = NULL;
HDC hdcPctrBox = NULL;

hdcPctrBox = GetWindowDC(hwndPctrBox); //hwndPctrBox is the handle of picturebox
originalPen = SelectObject(hdcPctrBox, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
//create the two pens

//in the end release resources
SelectObject(hdcPctrBox, originalPen);
DeleteObject(hLinePen);
DeleteObject(hLinePenErase);
ReleaseDC(hwndPctrBox, hdcPctrBox);
```

valter

Comment: There is a good link for GDI and visual c++ [click here](http://www.ucancode.net/faq/feature.htm)

Comment: This is exactly what my solution does.. it creates a double-buffer and paints via BitBlt...

Comment: Hello, thank you so much! I will start study this link this morning and I will try your code!

Comment: Just to know: is it possible to use this kind of coding in a clr project or should I use an MFC application? Because I tried it including `windef.h` and `windows.h` and the compiler keeps giving me errors.

Comment: @Emi987 Use plain c++. I can help you with the GUI staff.

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately I need to use CLI to make a WinForm app but I do actually appreciate your code valter! I keep on trying and I will try to adapt my code to your solution!

Comment: @Emi987 Use:                                                `#include "stdafx.h"  #include <windows.h>  #pragma comment( lib, "gdi32" )   #pragma comment( lib, "user32" )  #pragma comment( lib, "kernel32" )` and possibly [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975057/taking-a-screenshot-c-cli)

Comment: I've tried your code and it works perfectly! But it persists the same problem. I declare `PolyLine`outside the `for`, so the code saves all the point into the array then it plots them onto the screen. It is very fasty, I have to admit. But, if I put the `PolyLine` inside the `for`I'm able to see my plot growing - the code places line after line until the `for` is active but it's quite slow again. It costs 400 ms of time. If you use plain c++ and gdi it is an easy task to try and verify!

Comment: @Emi987 The code as it is does not grow (as growing is to fast to see) but rather drawing different plots(1000 lines each) every time. In order to see it "growing" you have to draw every 16msec or slower. If you go faster you will have tearing effects and other stuff. The solution for growing is to draw a line every 16msec and move the plot to the left or right(your preference). I will see how to do it

Comment: @Emi987 You are inserting in the for loop `Polyline` and `BitBlt`. Every `BitBlt` takes about(depending on the system) 500micro to 1msec so 1000 `BitBlt's` takes ~500msec as you said.

Comment: @Emi987 check the edit. It will draw as fast as possible but the results of this speedy drawing are unpredictable.

Comment: @valter I'm really amazed!! It works like never!! On the `pictureBox` still remaining some points not erased just like frekles but I'm sure I'll get rid of it!. By the way it is fast like a rocket! You were so kind, I really appreciate your help! Thank you so much, you gave me a lot of good information and I've learned a lot from you! Yay!

Comment: I found out how to save the image as bitmap. It works so, I won't harrass you with all this newbie questions! Thank you so much again, you were so fine!

Comment: @Emi987 You dont harrass me at all. If you have any other question please ask.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to implement your own painting class. Derive your own class from "Panel" or "UserControl" and do the following in the constructor, which activates double buffering and optimized drawing:

```
public ref class MyPaintControl : public System::Windows::Forms::UserControl
{
public:
    MyPaintControl()
    {
        this->SetStyle(System::Windows::Forms::ControlStyles::AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this->SetStyle(System::Windows::Forms::ControlStyles::DoubleBuffer, true);
        this->SetStyle(System::Windows::Forms::ControlStyles::ResizeRedraw, true);
        this->SetStyle(System::Windows::Forms::ControlStyles::UserPaint, true);
    }

 // And then implement your painting in OnPaint:

protected: 
    virtual void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs^ e)
    {
      // Do painting...
      System::Drawing::Brush^ br = gcnew System::Drawing::SolidBrush(this->BackColor);
      e->Graphics->FillRectangle(br, this->ClientRectangle);
      delete br;

     // Do other paintings...
    }

    // This function might be called if new data arrived...
    public:
      void UpdateArea(int daten)  // pass data here, if you want...
      {
        // Store the data in a member variable...

        // force a redraw:
        this->InvalidateRect(); // this will force a "OnPaint"
      }
}
```

Then embedd this control in your UI. This should improve your painting very much!

Also this works, even if you move or resize your window. Be aware, that painting should *always* be done in "OnPaint"!

Comment: Thanks for replying! This one seems interesting, I'll give for sure a try! I would like to ask you if it is possible to have a real time plotting with this one!

Comment: @Emi987: Yes, you can make a real-time plotting system... by the way: To force a redraw, you need to invalidate the rectacle (InvalidateRect). Also for very fast systems, you might need to to some "dirwct" drawing... which is not often needed... the easier way is to use "OnPaint"...

Comment: I actually appreciate your help Jochen. Honestly, it's not clear to me how to convert my code into this one but it seems the right way. I'm sorry if I'm exploiting you, but do you have other suggestions to give me to make my code work that way? :) Thanks so much again!

Comment: 1. Create a derived class from "UserControl" / 2. Add this control to your "main-control/window" / 3. Add a property "MainWindow/Controls" to your new UserControl which points to the data of the "MainWIndow/Control" => Then you have access to all the data and can paint your content... also you can call any function in your UserControl, to update the data / force a redraw. What else do you need?

Comment: I don't know how to create a derived class. I'm googling to find out how to do!

Comment: `public ref class MyPaintClass : public System::Windows::Forms::UserControl
{` I also modified the example to reflect this...

Comment: Ok, I did myPanel and I can display it on my Form. I'm keeping on asking, sorry man! ;) How can I raise "OnPaint" event when I click my button? When I code a DrawLine directly on "OnPaint" function I have it without any clicking

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'm still new to C++, so I don't know how to do this properly but I'm sure I will try!

Comment: By the way: You are NOT doing C++, you are doing C++/CLI which makes mostly no sence... please use C#

Answer (score 0):

I would like to update the state of my coding.
I used the method posted by Jochen. It is very fast but it does not suit my application or maybe I'm not able to adapt it. What I need to do, is to update constantly my plot. At time t0, I should draw a line. At time t1, when I store a new line, I should draw the new line and add this to the previous one. The plot must be "alive". I tried to derive a panel class and override the `OnPaint`event but my plot refreshing only if all lines are stored and displayed.

Comment: So you want to draw **one** line at a time? What is the time interval for every line drawn? What is the size of the PictureBox?

Comment: Yep, exactly. I don't want to plot, for istance, 1000 line at the same time. My  `pictureBox` has size (1200, 600), but in my code I manage to use some scaling to use an area of (1000, 500). Everytime my  `for` cycle evaluates a new value, I'd like to update my plot. I don't want to wait all the values to be evaluated. If you run my code, you can see it works as intended. It is just a bit slow.

Comment: I can not test your code because i am not using c++ or c++-cli, only plain c. Your task is easy and can be done extermely fast. For me drawing a 1200x600 image using gdi+ can take about 40frames/sec and using gdi about 1000frames/sec. So gdi is no brainer. I will see a solution.

Comment: In order for your chart to be "alive", you have to move all the chart 1px to the left and draw to the end. The x coordinate of the new point must be always the same e.g 1050. What you are doing, is drawing at cycles e.g from 50 to 1050 and repeat.

Comment: Thank you valter for your effort! Unfortunately, it's not clear to me how to move my chart to the left and evaluate new points. Can you please give me a bit more details on how to modify my code and run your solution? I can't wait to try it!

Comment: I am working for the code but i need to know the update time for drawing each new line. For example draw line1 <- `time?` -> draw line2.... What is the acceptable `time`?

Comment: I would be able to reach 1000 lines plotted in 10/20 ms. So, I think would be enough one new line every 10 microseconds.

Comment: You can draw each line in 10microsec and less but your screen will not be able to draw show fast. You have to synchronize with your screen refresh time e.g 60Hz every 16msec. So draw 1000 lines every 16msec. This is possible. In my machine (two years old, no graphic card) i can draw 2000 lines in 12msec. Is this ok?

Comment: I think it's perfect!